# Element Centering From The Left Instead Of Center

Tags: css, centering

I am having a issue with centering my element. The element keeps centering from the left most side instead of the center. Is there anyway to fix this? Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code

```
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -25px;;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
```

The red dot is the center of the screen (horizontally wise)[And here is what's happening:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you please give us the HTML for this so it's easier for us to help you, thank you.

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: Yeah, it is likely the issue is in the HTML code. Would be able to share it with us?